# Create column with Cast in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to create some columns that has some autogenerated data in it using values from other columns in the table

I know that if i do something like this it'll work

```
ALTER TABLE Directions ADD RevisedLat INT
UPDATE Directions SET RevisedLat = CAST(Latitude*3200/90 AS INT)
```

however, i want to do the cast in the add query and this doesn't work

```
ALTER TABLE Directions ADD RevisedLat CAST(Latitude*3200/90 AS INT)
```

what is the best way to get this working? just do the add and update?

Comment: Yep. Alter and Update.

Comment: you mean you're adding a computed column?.. that would be like `ALTER TABLE Directions ADD RevisedLat AS (Latitude*3200/90)`..

Comment: thanks, that works

Answer (score 3):

try a computed column

```
ALTER TABLE Directions 
ADD RevisedLat  as (Cast(Latitude*3200/90  as INT))
```